# Как можно упростить цикл for?

Tags: python

Как можно упростить выражение?

```
policy = []
for i in res2:
   policy.append(tuple(i))

print policy
```

Answer (score 5):

```
policy = [tuple(o) for o in res2]
```

Comment: Можно также убрать вызов функции `tuple` заменив её конструированием с помощью литерала: `policy = [(o, ) for o in res2]`

Comment: А вот это уже спорное предположение, так как в вопросе про природу элементов res2 ничего не сказано, и `(o, )` может привести к другому результату

Comment: Действительно, если будет iterable, то поведение изменится. Поторопился.

Answer (score 5):

`map(tuple, res2)`

Comment: Важно отметить, что список при исполнении выражения будет получен только в python 2, в python 3 для этого эффекта необходимо вызвать функцию `list`: `policy = list(map(tuple, res2))`

Comment: По мнению Гвидо, list comprehension ([f(i) for i in a]) использовать предпочительнее, чем map. Он даже хотел удалить map и filter из python3:  http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196